# Where is the config (application properties) file for TimeMachine settings and the path excludes?

Tags: time-machine, preferences

Where is the config (application properties) file for TimeMachine settings and the path excludes?

You know, that what you might click and add in `TimeMachine Settings > Options ...`

Can't find anything in `~/Library/Preferences`.
But settings are per user and not system-wide?!

System Command / Library seems to be named `com.apple.prefs.backup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, found it:

```
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist
```

They ARE saved in the Systems-Library Preferences. All user settings are entitled in this file ;/

see http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2010051917410348 => http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071207104354466

---

P.S: According to [@M-K's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/131403/5626) the default exclusion list is found under

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/StdExclusions.plist
```