# Scripting Timemachine exclusion lists

Tags: time-machine

Is it possible to script the exclude lists for Time Machine when setting up a new machine?

For example, for a new machine I would like to setup the following exclusion list:

[image]

Comment: related http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/63778/8605

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tmutil` command line tool, included with OS X, supports the ability to add and remove items from the exclusion list.

```
sudo tmutil addexclusion ~/.ivy2
```

See the [tmutil manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/tmutil.8.html) page for more information about this tool's options.

As `tmutil` is a command line tool, it can be incorporated into AppleScripts using **do shell script**, combined with Automator workflows using the **Run shell script** step, or as part of a traditional shell script.